# SQL query to Group last 3 months of data by individual months and counts

Tags: sql, count

I have a DB with Emails that have been sent out. Columns are `SendDate` and `MailFrom`. Each email sent is a record.

I would like to produce a report that shows how many emails have gone out for the last 3 months grouped by individual month and From address eg:

```
From Adresss        Nov 2015    Dec 2015  Jan 2016

clienta@mailer.com    36         28         14
clientb@mailer.com    13         6          8
```

Sample Data would simply be :

```
FromAdresss              SendDate
clienta@mailer.com        25/11/15
clientb@mailer.com        20/12/15
clientb@mailer.com        21/11/15
```

I've tried various GROUP BY and count methods, but cant get as far as creating the dynamic headers and the counts below them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That date format isn't ANSI SQL, so the answer will probably include product specific SQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FromAddress,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(SendDate) = 11 AND YEAR(SendDate) = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Nov2015,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(SendDate) = 12 AND YEAR(SendDate) = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Dec2015,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(SendDate) = 1 AND YEAR(SendDate) = 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Jan2016
FROM tableName
GROUP BY FromAddress
```

I have used MONTH() and YEAR() functions in SQL Server to extract month and year from SendDate column. You can use the respective functions provided in the DBMS you are using in above query.

To make it dynamic you can use [**DATEDIFF()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189794.aspx) function as below

```
SELECT FromAddress,
       SUM( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SendDate,GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ,
       SUM( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SendDate,GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ,
       SUM( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SendDate,GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM tableName
GROUP BY FromAddress
```

Comment: This is brilliant and works, but can it be modified to be dynamic, ie last 3 months relative to today and not fixed.?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(FromAddress) AS RecordCount,
    DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(SendDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 1, 2), 101)) AS 'MONTH',
    DATEPART(YY, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(SendDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 1, 2), 101)) AS 'YEAR'
FROM tableName
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(SendDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 1, 2), 101)),
    DATEPART(YY, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(SendDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(SendDate, 1, 2), 101))
```

As above, but since your dates aren't standard SQL, you have to do a bit extra work around them